# Ubuntu, dotnet run works, but executing the output binary says you must install .NET

Tags: .net, ubuntu

Ubuntu 22.04. I installed .NET 7 SDK from MS repository. I created a project using `dotnet new console`, and `dotnet run` outputs `Hello, world!`, but if I navigate to the output directory and run the app directly, it says install .NET. What is wrong?

PS: After posting this, I have noticed that `DOTNET_ROOT` is `/usr/lib/dotnet`, and `dotnet` is in `/usr/share/dotnet`. Is that the cause? But I did not set the variable manually, so I do not know where the variable `DOTNET_ROOT` is defined. I have searched all the relevant profile files in my home directory or under `/etc`, but I could not find `DOTNET_ROOT`.

```
~/dottest/bin/Debug/net7.0$ ./dottest 
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/test/dottest/bin/Debug/net7.0/dottest
Architecture: x64
App host version: 7.0.1
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64&apphost_version=7.0.1
```

Output of `dotnet --info`

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.101
 Commit:    bb24aafa11

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.22.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.1
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/lib/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Comment: Well, I "purged" everything that started with "dotnet", rebooted the PC, and then re-did the whole installation process from adding the "Microsoft Feed" as [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2204-microsoft-package-feed) says. Now, if I run "dotnet --info", it says that "Environment variables: Not set" and the output executable can run.